# How to find xPath of a tag in HTML

Tags: c#, html, xpath, xhtml

please help me to resolve this problem :(,
I'm working with BrowserControl of C#, I have a html document file like this:

```
<html>
<title>
news
</title>
<body>
<br>
<br/>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li><li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk2</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

when my mouse is clicked on `<li>Black tea</li>`, how i can get xPath of this tag? By using BrowserControl of C#, i just get innerHTML or OuterHTML or Text of current position of mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the XPath of this tag programatically with the code that you have. You will in fact have to build the XPath yourself. However, this should be trivial if you use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

The HTML Agility pack allows you to load the HTML document (which is generally NOT well formed XML) as if it was properly formed XML and use XPath queries on it. What you can then do is load the document in the HTML Agility Pack, search for the node programatically (using XPath to search for elements that contain a certain string for example), then when you have the node from the search, you can build an XPath by walking up through each parent.

So altogether:

1. Read node on mouse click, gives -

   ```
   <li>Black Tea</li>
   ```
2. Parse contents and node name - gives

   ```
   Contents = Black Tea, Name = li
   ```
3. Build XPath query:

   ```
   //Name[contains(., Contents)]
   ```

   ( in this case, //li(., 'Black Tea') )
4. Traverse each parent, to build an xpath query, gives - ul/li, then li/ul/li, then ul/li/ul/li, then body/ul/li/ul/li and finally -

   ```
   html/body/ul/li/ul/li
   ```

So the key here is to get the document in a traversable way via HTML Agility Pack, create a general query to get the node, then build the full query from the node.

Does this help?